# values of hidden input are 1 short each time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden input which appends into a table, this is below:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage' value='" + GetFormImageCount() + "' /></form>");
$image.append($fileImage);
```

Below is the function which determines the value of the hidden input:

```
function GetFormImageCount(){ 
  return $('.imageuploadform').length;
}
```

How it hould work is that form 1 is appended in table row 1, this means the value of the hidden input should be 1. Problem is that it isn't doing this, the value is 0.

When form 2 is appended it appends into table row 2, this means the value of the hidden input should be 2 but problem is that value for this input is 1.

So my question is why is the value of the hudden inputs are 1 less than what the values should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it's working as it should. You're selecting all `.imageuploadform` elements, there are **none** at the beginning so the `length` is 0.

You can either +1 to the value when setting the attribute or append the element before setting the value.

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target_image' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >
<input type='hidden' class='numimage' name='numimage'/></form>");
$image.append($fileImage);
setTimeout(function () {
    $fileImage.attr('value', GetFormImageCount());
}, 0);
```

The `setTimeout` function is used to wait for the DOM to append the element, be careful ;) I'd go with the *+1 solution* as it's easier.

Comment: You're right.. the count is done before the dom is updated so it returns the right value.. You have to append the form first and then to count the existing forms and then you achieve what you want